# How to generate a url that will expire after 30 minutes?

Tags: node.js, url, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project where I had to give a url to the user which will get expire after 30 minutes. I have a uuid for user and this uuid is unique for every user. When the user click the url it should hit the cloud function in google cloud and retrieve the data from firestore, this retrieved data is user information and this information should be displayed.

It will be helpful if done in NodeJS.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Store a property called `expiresAt` in your `Firestore Database`. This property will contain a Date String which will be `Current Time + 30 Minutes`

**Step 2:** Check the URL from your `node.js` backend server `if the current Time is less than expiresAt or not`. If it's true then send the proper response, otherwise, send an error message to the client.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution with automatic expiry: when your cloud function is called:

1. get the data you want to expose from firestore
2. write the data a a file in your cloud function environment
3. upload the file to Google Cloud Storage bucket (GCS object)
4. create a signed URL to download the object with a duration of 30 minutes
5. return the signed url as a response of the cloud function

Here are, an [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-nodejs) in node for creating a signed URL, and an [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage